# RNN classification constantly output the same value

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, text-classification, recurrent-neural-network

I was using rnn to do some classification job, and success on one task. But when I use the similar model on another task, what strange happened.
These are some information. The value above is prediction, another is target.

```
Step 147, learning rate is 0.050000000000000, cost is 0.333333
[[ 1.00000000e+00 1.94520349e-16 5.00660735e-10 8.93992450e-11
 6.57709234e-11 2.75211902e-11]]
[[ 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
Step 148, learning rate is 0.050000000000000, cost is 0.333333
[[ 1.00000000e+00 2.51522596e-16 6.98772706e-10 1.32924283e-10
 2.06628145e-10 1.63214553e-10]]
[[ 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
Step 149, learning rate is 0.050000000000000, cost is 1.07511e-18
[[ 1.00000000e+00 6.98618693e-16 2.44663956e-09 2.75078210e-10
 4.09978718e-10 4.69938033e-10]]
[[ 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

It seems all the output converge to the same value. In other words, with every input, the model output the same prediction regardless the cost.

To provide more information, this is my model structure:

```
class SequenceClassification:

def __init__(self, data, target, dropout, learning_rate,num_hidden=2500, num_layers=2):
    self.data = data
    self.target = target
    self.dropout = dropout
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self._num_hidden = num_hidden
    self._num_layers = num_layers
    self.prediction
    self.precision
    self.optimize 

@lazy_property
def prediction(self):
    # Recurrent network.
    network = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(self._num_hidden)
    network = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(network, output_keep_prob = self.dropout)
    network = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([network]*self._num_layers)
    output, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(network, data, dtype=tf.float32)
    # Select last output.
    output = tf.transpose(output, [1, 0, 2])
    print(output.get_shape())
    last = tf.gather(output, int(output.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
    # Softmax layer.
    weight, bias = self._weight_and_bias(
        self._num_hidden, int(self.target.get_shape()[1]))
    prediction = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)
    return prediction

@lazy_property
def cost(self):
    #cross_entropy = -tf.reduce_sum(self.target * tf.log(self.prediction+1e-10))
    #loss =cross_entropy
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.target - self.prediction))
    return loss

@lazy_property
def optimize(self):
    optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(self.learning_rate)
    return optimizer.minimize(self.cost), self.cost, self.prediction

@lazy_property
def precision(self):
    correct = tf.equal(
        tf.argmax(self.target, 1), tf.argmax(self.prediction, 1))
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))

@staticmethod
def _weight_and_bias(in_size, out_size):
    weight = tf.get_variable("W", shape=[in_size, out_size],
       initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    bias = tf.get_variable("B", shape=[out_size],
       initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
    return weight, bias
```

And the input is in the shape[datanum, maxstep, vectorsize], I use zeros to pad them into the same size.

I can't understand what happen because it works well on the former task.
Additionally, this classification task works well when I was using DL4J:
This is the model:

```
MultiLayerConfiguration conf = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
        .optimizationAlgo(OptimizationAlgorithm.STOCHASTIC_GRADIENT_DESCENT).iterations(1)
        .updater(Updater.RMSPROP)
        .regularization(true).l2(1e-5)
        .weightInit(WeightInit.XAVIER)
        .gradientNormalization(GradientNormalization.ClipElementWiseAbsoluteValue).gradientNormalizationThreshold(1.0)
        .learningRate(0.08)
        .dropOut(0.5)
        .list(2)
        .layer(0, new GravesBidirectionalLSTM.Builder().nIn(vectorSize).nOut(1800)
                .activation("tanh").build())
        .layer(1, new RnnOutputLayer.Builder().activation("softmax")
                .lossFunction(LossFunctions.LossFunction.MCXENT).nIn(1800).nOut(6).build())
        .pretrain(false).backprop(true).build();

MultiLayerNetwork net = new MultiLayerNetwork(conf);
net.init();
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like it converges to `[1, 0...0]`. There's definitely something wrong with the setup. The cost is also strange, `1/3` or `0`. Also the learning rate does not decrease, meaning that it's trying to continue on that direction by ever-increasing weights (that means you don't have regularization). I would try to print out the loss values and prediction targets per example.

Comment: @drpng thanks for answer, I thought that the regularization only affect the over-fit? Do you mean without the regularization, the weight of inputs are not balanced, then makes the model tries to learn the first class regardless others?

Comment: Yes, it's for overfitting. Since the learning rate is not decreasing, it looks like the problem has (at least) a linear ambiguity, so using a regularizer will just force it have a fixed norm.

Comment: @drpng Um... The learning rate is controlled by myself. I set it to `0.5/(10*(step/200))` . But I will try your advice, hope it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to the "batch normalization". When you are evaluating your model, you should disable batch normalization.